# Why is Laravel Excel not finding the data in cells?

Tags: excel, laravel

I had this code working correctly and I came back to it and not laravel excel is not finding any data in the cells. I receive this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'shovel' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `customers` (`shovel`, `address`, `ice_melt`, `comments`, `stakes`, `name`, `phone_number`, `email`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 2020-12-28 20:13:08, 2020-12-28 20:13:08))"
trace: [{,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…},…]
```

Here is my import function:

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Customer;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsOnError;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class CustomerImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        //$address = Customer::select('address')->get();
        // foreach($address as $something){
        //     if ($something->address == $row['address']){
        //         return;
        //     }
        // }
        return new Customer([
            'shovel' => $row['shovel'],
            'address' => $row['address'],
            'ice_melt' => $row['icemelt'],
            'comments' => $row['comments'],
            'stakes' => $row['stakes'],
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'phone_number' => $row['phone'],
            'email' => $row['email'],

        ]);
    }
    public function rules(): array{
        return[
            'address' => Rule::unique('customers', 'address')
        ];
    }
}
```

And my controller:

```
public function fileImport(Request $request) 
    {
        $request->validate([
            'import_file' => 'required|file|mimes:xls,xlsx',
        ]);
        //$addresses = Customer::select('address');
        

        $path = $request->file('import_file');
        $data = Excel::import(new CustomerImport, $path); // Errors here

        return response()->json(['message' => 'uploaded successfully'], 200);
        return back();

    }
```

[image: here is the excel I am using to test]

Like I mentioned this was working previously so I must have some minor change. My routes are all still working for this it just seems the import file is where there is an issue.
Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: So I ended up creating a new excel sheet and copying the data over and it worked. Is there some hidden formating in Excel I need to watch out for?

Comment: Could you please share the output `$path`?

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same error. turns out it wasn't my code that was having an issue.
It the table row type.
or you can make the row nullable

Comment: So something I need to Change on the Excel sheet? What should I change it to?